# Play a sound when a new message arrives

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to play a sound everytime someone gets a new message. Right now I'm making a chatbox and I would like it to play a sound for the people who is watching the chatbox everytime a new message arrives (basically when someone inserts in the chatbox table in the db)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajax(){
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML = req.responseText;   
            }
        }
        req.open('GET', 'divisiones/chat.php', true);
        req.send();
    }
    //linea que hace que se refreseque la pagina cada segundo
    setInterval(function(){ajax();}, 1000);
</script>
 <div class="content-wrapper" onload="ajax();">
    <section class="content">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="box box-primary" style="background-color: #fffbf8;">
                    <div style="background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, white, white 1px, #fffbf8 1px, #fffbf8 8px);">
                        <div class="wrap">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div id="caja-chat">
                                    <div id="chat"></div>
                                </div>

                                <form method="POST" action="division_chat.php?auth=<?php echo $salt_key_check; ?>">
                                    <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre">
                                    <textarea name="mensaje" placeholder="Ingresa tu mensaje"></textarea>
                                    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
                                </form>

                                <?php
                                    if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {

                                        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
                                        $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];


                                        $consulta = "INSERT INTO division_chat VALUES (NULL,'$session_login_usr', '$mensaje', '$fptime', '$log_ip', '$divisionpd')";

                                        $ejecutar = $con_db->query($consulta);

                                        if ($ejecutar) {
                                            echo "<embed loop='false' src='beep.mp3' hidden='true' autoplay='true'>";
                                        }
                                    }

                                ?>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: I recommend reading https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/. It's a good place to start with the HTML5 Web Audio API. You can use JavaScript to load audio files and play/ pause them.

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: @DaZa Thank you!!!! So it can be done to get the sound everytime the chatbox get a new message?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you! I'll be working on it too. Any clue about the sound thing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the LAST `req.responseText` value somewhere so you can check to see if the new message is equal to that value.

For storing the `req.responseText` value I will be using HTML5 `localStorage`.

And then you can do something like this:

```
var LastMessage = localstorage.getItem('last_message');

if(req.responseText != LastMessage){

/////Play your sound here/////
$('#audio').play();

}
```

Make sure you have this somewhere in your page:

```
<audio id="audio" src="audio.mp3"></audio>
```